# Generate settings-security.xml file for maven password encryption

Tags: maven, password-encryption

I want to encrypt my Apache Archiva server password using [maven password encryption](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html).

I did:

```
mvn --encrypt-master-password 12345
```

Fine. I got an encrypted password inside brackets.
Then:

```
mvn --encrypt-password 12345
```

Maven complains:

```
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/myUserName/.m2/settings-security.xml (No such file or directory)
[ERROR] Caused by: /home/myUserName/.m2/settings-security.xml (No such file or directory)
```

I understand that I should put my encrypted master password in the file settings-security.xml, but it does not exist at the default location and maven is not able to generate it.

What should be the content of this configuration file? How to generate it?

Comment: I had the same error during building a docker image (using fabric8 maven plugin) and pulling images from gitlab for this. I had a gitlab private token configured in my maven settings for this, which had been unencrypted and I needed no `security-settings.xml` till now. However, now with security-settings and encrypted gitlab private token in my maven settings, it works again.

Answer (score 38):

`mvn --encrypt-master-password` does not create a file `settings-security.xml`. You have to do it yourself.

So the procedure is:

1. Use the command `mvn --encrypt-master-password` to generate a master password. Remember this password.
2. Create a new file `settings-security.xml` in `${user.home}/.m2/`. For example, on Mac OS X or Ubuntu as `~/.m2/settings-security.xml`.

Write into this file:

```
<settingsSecurity>
  <master>OUTPUT OF THE COMMAND: mvn --encrypt-master-password</master>
</settingsSecurity>
```

e.g.:

```
<settingsSecurity>
  <master>{jSMOWnoPFgsHVpMvz5VrIt5kRbzGpI8u+9EF1iFQyJQ=}</master>
</settingsSecurity>
```

After that the maven encrypt command works on the command line:

`mvn --encrypt-password`

As mentioned by khmarbaise, more detailed information can be found [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html)

Comment: But the `mvn --encrypt-master-password` gives error that the `settings-security.xml` does not exist *AND ERRORS OUT* - so we do not even have any encrypted password to add into that file

Answer (score 0):

Well I had the same error when I run the command : `mvn --encrypt-password 1234`

> [ERROR] Error executing Maven. [ERROR] java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> E:\Users\XX.m2\settings-security.xml (The system cannot find the file
> specified) [ERROR] Caused by: E:\Users\XX.m2\settings-security.xml
> (The system cannot find the file specified)

It was not fixed even after creating the *settings-security.xml* file.

It was fixed and I got the encrypted password after using:

```
mvn --encrypt-master-password 1234
```