# error while using maven for password encryption

Tags: maven-3

I am trying to encrypt the password using maven by following this link- [Generate settings-security.xml file for maven password encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503336/generate-settings-security-xml-file-for-maven-password-encryption). But, in the step after creating master password and creating the file settings-security.xml, but while trying to run the command- mvn --encrypt-password '!12345', I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: start tag unexpected character { (position: TEXT seen <settingsSecurity>\n<master{... @2:9) 
[ERROR] Caused by: start tag unexpected character { (position: TEXT seen <settingsSecurity>\n<master{... @2:9) 
abhinashkumarjha@C02DP5F7MD6R ~ % mvn --encrypt-password '!Abhi@090342'
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: start tag unexpected character { (position: START_TAG seen <settingsSecurity><master{... @1:26) 
[ERROR] Caused by: start tag unexpected character { (position: START_TAG seen <settingsSecurity><master{... @1:26)
```

My settings-security.xml looks like this:

```
<settingsSecurity>
    <master{42xI34HcwGIH/t9Bhr5P4ctsVIjOtvPO81b2eb9uYWY=}</master>
</settingsSecurity>
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: `<master` -> `<master>`

Comment: Shameful on my part. Now it's working. Only if I had opened in any browser would have thrown this error. Thanks!!